# Google Map API working with Store Locator and My Maps

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a map with the [Google store locator library](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html)

I was wondering if I could directly pass an URL to the API in order for editors to add / remove / edit places (inside Google maps / My Maps) afterwards without having to reupload a file.

Does it make any sense ?

Can I use something : https://maps.google.fr/maps/ms?msid=XXXX&msa=0&output=json ?

Thanks in advance,

J.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you correctly. 
Just finished my first MapsAPI project so i hope my answer fits.

You actually can pass some parameters, where you can set the library (drawing, geometry, places...) to the API when you call/initialize it:

```
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

The [Wiki](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) says:

> To load the JavaScript code for the Maps JavaScript API, you include a bootstrap URL on your page, of the form https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js. This bootstrap request loads all of the main JavaScript objects and symbols for use in the Maps JavaScript API.

There are 5 libraries available.

I´m not completely sure if I got you right tho:

What do you mean by reupload a file?

 - if you want to remove a single store from your map, I know 2 possible ways (there may be more):

1. Set Marker visibility = false ([see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove))
2. Set Marker Map = null  ( [yourMarker.setMap(null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594130/how-to-hide-google-maps-api-markers-with-jquery) )

Looking forward for your reply :D