# Get Marker By Id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i am trying to reach a Google-Maps Marker by his ID.

Every marker has his own id like `MapMarker1`, `MapMarker2` and so on...

I want to hide markes like:

`$("#MapMarker1").hide();`

But the response is always empty so i think Jquery doesnt look into the markers propertys?

Is there a possibility to hide markers by id from Jquery ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9594181/3293843

Comment: Sorry but this is not a answer of my question. Its about hide markers from outside the map not adding a visible(false) flag on onclick.

Comment: You don't need to att the click handler, choose one that fits you :)